# Sometimes my http server does not respond and I see errors like connection reset or timout

Tags: apache-2.2, connection

Here is the graph from munin that might help
[image: munin graoh]

and also here is my `http.conf`:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   40
ServerLimit      2048
MaxClients       2048
MaxRequestsPerChild  8000
</IfModule>
```

PHP generate page in few milliseconds but I don't know why client cant receive it properly. And you also see the connections graph witch has fell in last minutes. I was not able to load almost any page on my website in that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see from network point of view is too many TIME_WAIT=9.76K(I am not sure what is assured means).time_wait is a condition when your system is run out of socket because of many tcp connection are repeatedly open and closed.You can confirm it using netstat -an.You can tune these parameters

```
             net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
             net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
```

tcp_tw_recycle - BOOLEAN
    Enable fast recycling TIME-WAIT sockets. Default value is 0.
    It should not be changed without advice/request of technical
    experts. Enabling this option is not recommended since this 
    causes problems when working with NAT(Network Address
    Translation).

tcp_tw_reuse - BOOLEAN
    Allow to reuse TIME-WAIT sockets for new connections when it is
    safe from protocol viewpoint. Default value is 0.
    It should not be changed without advice/request of technical
    experts.

But before that take a tcpdump and check the new connection,also check with your application team if these many connection are desired.

Comment: Sorry we are not team I am all alone. Thank you I am googling about your answer